# Merge a .gpx with a DEM

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, convert, gpx

I have two files, a DEM and a .GPX. How can I mix the two files so that the .gpx is part of the DEM (in black and white), but rendering the color at an elevation 10m higher than the DEM?

The color of the .GPX should be set to black and white, lighter or darker depending on how high it is above the DEM.

I tried with Raster > Conversion but I cannot see the output.

[image: Raster-Conversion-Rasterize]

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

1. Run Menu Raster > Conversion > [Rasterize](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#rasterize-vector-to-raster) the line. Set the value for `A fixed value to burn` to 10 and define `Output raster size units` (either pixels or layer units) and set the resolution you want. Maybe convert the line to a projected CRS (as of now, you seem to use `EPSG:4326`).
2. Use Menu Raster > [Raster calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_analysis.html#raster-calculator) to add the rasterized layer to the DEM.

*Step 1: Rasterize*
[image]

Comment: The output of the step 1, is not correct. The lowest point is -3,40282e+38 and the highest +3,40282e+38. Is like empty... I cannot see the output.

Comment: Hm - without seeing your date + project, it's difficult to say

Comment: I updated the question with new screenshots. Thank you Babel :)